# UriFormatException: 無効な URI: URI の形式を決定できませんでした。 の対処法方法が知りたい

Tags: c#

提示コードですが以下の例外が発生してしまう原因が知りたいです。URLはAPIサイトのものを入力してパラメータを設定しているのですがなぜ無効という例外が発生してまうのでしょうか？参考サイトを参考にソースコードを記述しましたが原因がわかりません。
おそらくリダイレクトURLが違うのかと思うのですがどれが間違えているのでしょうか？

###### 確認したこと

`Console.WriteLine(url);`部にして以下ように出力されているためURLは確実に来ています

```
https://mstdn.jp/api/v1/apps?client_name=test&redirect_uris=https%3A%2F%2Fmstdn.jp%2Fauth%2Fsign_in
```

###### 知りたいこと

リダイレクトURLの正しい設定方法と以下の例外が発生してしまう原因が知りたい。

###### ソースコードの処理内容

提示コードは参考サイトのマストドンapiを用いて`OAuth トークンの取得に使用できるクライアント アプリケーションを登録します。`をするコードです。
`GetLastUrl`関数はリダイレクトURLを取得す関数です。

###### 例外

`var req = WebRequest.Create(q);`コード部にて

```
UriFormatException: 無効な URI: URI の形式を決定できませんでした。
```

###### 参考サイト

API : https://docs.joinmastodon.org/methods/apps/
ソースコード: https://argius.hatenablog.jp/entry/20131113/1384352397

###### ソースコード

```cs
        public static async Task<string> GetLastUrl(string url)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko");

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            return response.RequestMessage.RequestUri.ToString();
        }

        private static async Task test_run()
        {
            //リダイレクトURLを設定
            //Console.WriteLine("あああ");
            Task<string> task = GetLastUrl("https://mstdn.jp/web/home");
            //Task<string> task = GetLastUrl("https://mstdn.jp/api/v1/apps");
            task.Wait();

            //パラメータを設定
            Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                { "client_name", "test" },
                { "redirect_uris", task.Result }
            };
            var para = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);
            var tt = para.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            string url = "https://mstdn.jp/api/v1/apps?" + tt;


            string q = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(url);


            //Console.WriteLine("encoded q: " + q);

            // HTTPアクセス
            Console.WriteLine(url);

            var req = WebRequest.Create(q);

            Console.WriteLine("bbbbbb");

            req.Headers.Add("Accept-Language:ja,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3");
            var res = req.GetResponse();

            // レスポンス(JSON)をオブジェクトに変換
            ServiceResult info;
            using (res)
            {
                using (var resStream = res.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ServiceResult));
                    info = (ServiceResult)serializer.ReadObject(resStream);
                }
            }
            
            Console.ReadKey();
        }


        private static async void test()
        {
            Task.WaitAll(test_run());

        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           // t();

            test();



        }


        [DataContract]
        public class ServiceResult
        {

            [DataMember]
            public string id { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string name { get; set; }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UrlEncode するとエラーが発生しますね
エンコードによってこんな文字列になっているからではないでしょうか

`https%3a%2f%2fmstdn.jp%2fapi%2fv1%2fapps%3fclient_name%3dtest%26redirect_uris%3dhttps%253A%252F%252Fmstdn.jp%252Fauth%252Fsign_in`

エンコードなし

```
using System;
using System.Net;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create ("https://mstdn.jp/api/v1/apps?client_name=test&redirect_uris=https%3A%2F%2Fmstdn.jp%2Fauth%2Fsign_in");
        Console.Write(request);
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/F54818

エンコードあり

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;

public class Program
{

    public static void Main()
    {
         string encoded_uri = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("https://mstdn.jp/api/v1/apps?client_name=test&redirect_uris=https%3A%2F%2Fmstdn.jp%2Fauth%2Fsign_in");
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create (encoded_uri);
        Console.Write(request);
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/F54818

Comment: `var res = req.GetResponse();`の行でエラー`WebException: リモート サーバーがエラーを返しました: (403) 使用不可能`が発生するのですがこれはこの件とは無関係なのでしょうか？

Comment: リクエスト先でのエラーは別問題ではないでしょうか